# How can I subscribe to the podcast?

Tags: support, podcast

I have a [Windows Phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone) with the default *Podcasts* app. How can I subscribe to the Stack Overflow podcast?

I know I can find them [here](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange), but I don't see how I can subscribe so my podcast app automatically downloads the last few episodes. I guess an RSS feed would suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official RSS feed of [the podcasts](https://feeds.simplecast.com/XA_851k3) was

```
http://blog.stackexchange.com/feed/podcast/
```

as explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264272/158100) from [D.G.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/281117/d-g) over at MSE.

But now (March, 2021) it seems to be at `https://feeds.simplecast.com/XA_851k3`.

Notice that you have alternative platforms to stream those podcasts to you

- [Apple Podcasts](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-stack-overflow-podcast/id1033688462)
- [Google Podcasts](https://www.google.com/podcasts?feed=aHR0cHM6Ly9mZWVkcy5zaW1wbGVjYXN0LmNvbS9YQV84NTFrMw%3D%3D)
- [Overcast](https://overcast.fm/p1359898-OviOni)
- [Soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange)
- [Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/show/0e5eoM6w7eW9Wu7wMA04Tr?si=6k4M_iTyT2yA2IV-mPloXA)

The main page for the podcasts on the blog [is here](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/).

Answer (score 5):

As of October 2023, the link is https://feeds.simplecast.com/XA_851k3

Comment: Not any more, as of today a 404 error is returned

Comment: The 404 is for the `stackoverflow.blog` one. The `feeds.simplecast.com` one works (and has worked for a long time (at least several months)).